# Selected tabs links to original link location

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using jquery UI tabs to create tabbed content. When a tab title is selected, I want it to link to the original location.

```
    $(function() {
  $("div.tabs").tabs("div.items > div"); 
    });

<div id="items">
    <div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab"><a href="http//www.example1.com">Tab title 1</a></div>
    <div class="tab"><a href="http//www.example2.com">Tab Title 2</a></div>
    <div class="tab"><a href="http//www.example3.com">Tab title 3</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

When not-selected clicking on tab title 1 shows the tab content.
After being selected, the tab title 1 would link to http//www.example1.com.

Comment: You'll probably need an If Else statement   http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Comment: that I understand, but how do you change the functionality of the link ?

Comment: $('div.tabs').bind('click',function(){})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a class if the tab had been clicked once already, and then used mouse down to trigger the link.

```
$(".tabs").tabs(".items > div"); 
$(".tabs .tab:first a").addClass("lasttab");
        $(".tabs .tab").mousedown(function() {
            if ($(this).find('a').hasClass("lasttab")) {
        window.location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    }
    $(".tabs .lasttab").removeClass("lasttab");
    $(this).find("a").addClass("lasttab");
});
```